# Python matching lines of a file with a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching

High-level requirement is that I need an equivalent of "grep -f match_str_file search_file".

I have a list of strings which I need to find in a given text file.
The string may occur anywhere in any line of file.

What would be an efficient way to achieve this?

```
matchstr = ['string1', 
'string2', 
'string3',
...
'string1000']

with open('some_text_file') as file:
    for line in file:
        if <any matchstr> in line:
            print( 'Found a match!', matchstr[x])
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why is this question downvoted? Being a simple question doesn't make it wrong. If there was any other reason, it should be specified.

Comment: What is your metric for "efficiency". What "inefficient" method did you try? Why did it not work.

Comment: You should read the message when someone throws in a close vote. It will generally explain the downvote that came with it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
matchstr = ['string1', 
'string2', 
'string3',
...
'string1000']

matches = []
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
while 1:
    lines = file.readlines(file_len("fjiop.txt"))
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines:
        matches.append([match, line] for match in matchstr if match in line)
```

Note that this will create generators inside generators so to loop through it use:

```
for i in matches:
    for j in i:
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But it doesn't help me. I specifically asked "What would be an efficient way to achieve this?" 
I need to compare 1M lines long file with 1K set of strings hundreds of times a day. Unless it is efficient, it won't make the cut.

Comment: Maybe this'll be faster; it is much faster on my computer.